# Authentication credentials were not provided with djangorestframework-jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am trying to use django rest_framework_jwt. I can get it to generate a token but when i try and send it in the header to a protected view i get 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'

The format of the header I am sending is:

```
"Authorization": "Token SomeRandomToken"
```

settings.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
    rest_framework.authtoken
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
   ),
}
```

views.py

```
class UserList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
               mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From looking at the [docs](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#installation) I would say you should remove the default `TokenAuthentication` from your 
`AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`

```
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
   ),
```

Also the header seems to have a different format:

> Now in order to access protected api urls you must include the `Authorization: JWT <your_token>` header.

Comment: Got the two documentations mixed up. Correcting the header fixed the issue. Thanks